# How do I show correctly an array of objects in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an array of objects in typescript:

```
data: {number: number, name: string, department: string, city: string}[] = [];
```

and I want to add employee data to data object and show it in a table (ng2-smart-table).

```
getEmployees(val:any): void {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees(val).subscribe((result) => {
        this.employee = result.items;

        for (let i = 0; i < this.employee.length; i++) {
          this.data["number"] = this.employee[i].number;
          this.data["name"] = this.employee[i].name;
          this.data["department"] = this.employee[i].departmentFk.name;
          this.data["city"] = this.employee[i].cityFk.name;

          console.log(this.data);
          this.source.append(this.data);
          this.source.refresh();
        }
    });
}

constructor() { this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data); }
```

What is happening is that its printing only the last values of the array employees... and I want to print every value in the array. Here's an example of what's happening:

[Table error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljh43.png)

[Console log array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muN0q.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use `this.data["name"]` just because `this.data.name` shows you an error?

Answer (score 1):

You could just bind to your employee array directly.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Department<th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e in employee">
      <td>{{e.number}}</td>
      <td>{{e.name}}</td>
      <td>{{e.departmentFk.name}}</td>
      <td>{{e.cityFk.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Edit:

The way you are updating your data array is incorrect.

Where you are doing `data["property"] = value`, you should instead be pushing new objects into the array.

```
data.push({
  number: this.employee[i].number,
  // etc...
})
```

But this seems redundant when you already have the employee array in the format you want. Your version is just attempting to copy one array to another without modifying it in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use `forEach` to perform this task in more convenient way:

```
getEmployees(val:any): void {
this._employeeService.getEmployees(val).subscribe((result) => {
    this.employee = result.items;
    this.employee.forEach((item) => {
        this.data.push({number : item.number,
                        name: item.name,
                        department: item.departmentFk.name,
                        city: item.cityFk.name});
    });
console.log(this.data);
```

Comment: Ivan's map solution is the best option if OP wants to create a new array of objects.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Map works faster than looping. My answer is just one more way to create objects array.

Comment: I was interested to see how much quicker map was than forEach. forEach is about 70% slower - I wasn't expecting it to be that different!

Answer (score 0):

Like others have mentioned, you need to be pushing new object into the data variable.

```
getEmployees(val:any): void {
    this._employeeService.getEmployees(val).subscribe((result) => {
        const employee = result.items;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.employee.length; i++) {
          this.data.push({
            'number': employee[i].number,
            'name': employee[i].name,
            'department': employee[i].departmentFk.name,
            'city': employee[i].cityFk.name,
          });
          this.source.append(this.data);
          this.source.refresh();
        }
    });
}

constructor() { this.source = new LocalDataSource(this.data); }
```

What you are attempting now updates current value of data each loop instead of appending new objects to the array.